# How to fix conflict of Swipers with Bootstrap tab-panes? Only 1st works correctly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

It's interesting that by putting each Swiper inside a tab-pane, only first one works correctly. Second one behaves very strange, like each slide width as 100%. But when I take them out of `panes` they work correctly.
I tried many different and possible approaches!

Is there any solution for this?

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#brands">Brands</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#categories">Categories</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="brands" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="swiper-container swiper_brands">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">a1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">a2</div>...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="categories" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="swiper-container swiper_categories">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">b1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">b2</div>...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.swiper_brands').swiper({
    slidesPerView: 5,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    autoplay: 0,
    spaceBetween: 15
});

$('.swiper_categories').swiper({
    slidesPerView: 5,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    autoplay: 0,
    spaceBetween: 15
});
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2896/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the exact issue, but if you put second tab items under timeout to enable the swipe it works fine, I think dom is not ready as items are not displaying in dom.
Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2897/

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.swiper_categories').swiper({
        slidesPerView: 3,
        mode: 'horizontal',
        autoplay: 0,
        spaceBetween: 15
    });
  }, 1000);
```

Let know if it helps.

Comment: OMG! You saved my time = life :-) Thanks a lot!